# How to access apigee endpoint?

Tags: api, rest, google-cloud-platform, reverse-proxy, apigee

I'm new to GCP and APIgee.

I'm trying to integrate an API as a reverse proxy in APIgee. Steps I have followed are :

- Create a Reverse Proxy
- Add the below details

  ```
           a. Name:                           simple-greetings-proxy
           b. Base path:                    /simple-greetings-proxy
           c. Target (Existing API):  https://mocktarget.apigee.net
  ```
- Leave default values in Policies page as it is as Pass through
- Deploy

It is not showing virtual hosts section. I'm not getting any host even after the creation of APIs so that I can test.

This looks like some configuration issue of apigee setup. [image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're following the 'build a simple API proxy' tutorial in the Apigee docs, like here:

https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/fundamentals/build-simple-api-proxy

The next section of the docs should have the info you need to proceed: 'Define the URL that clients see' > 'About virtual hosts'

[image]

Comment: Does apigee create default virtual host with free and trial account ? I suspect it does not

Comment: From this page (https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/fundamentals/virtual-hosts), I see: "Note: Free and trial accounts cannot create virtual hosts and are limited to the four virtual hosts created for them at Edge registration time."